# English translation in overriding of template with module

Tags: php, templates, module, smarty, prestashop

I need to override a class and a template. To achieve this, I choose to create a new module in order to not be blocked when Prestashop will update. For overriding class, I don't have problem.

The worry is in overriding template, fields are in English whereas in the rest of my website, they are in French (when I uninstall the module, they come back in French).

In my module, I override the template with this way :

```
public function hookDisplayOverrideTemplate($params)
    {
        $controllerName = get_class($params['controller']);
        $tpl = $this->local_path . 'override/tpl/' . $controllerName . '.tpl';
        if (file_exists($tpl))
        {
            return $tpl;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In my .tpl file, the fields which are not translate are like this :

```
{l s='Your addresses'}
```

So, I tried to insert the fr.php file in /my_module/translations/fr.php, and I edited it :

```
<?php
global $_MODULE;
$_MODULE = array();
$_MODULE['<{customaddresses}prestashop>customaddresses_3908e1afa0ff22fbf112aff3c5ba55c1'] = 'Vos adresses';
```

Then, I modified the .tpl file :

```
{l s='Your addresses' mod='customaddresses'}
```

My fields are still in English.
Someone has a solution to suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a great deal of research, I found my problem.

My solution is :   `$_MODULE['<{customaddresses}prestashop>address_0f68b904e33d9ac04605aecc958bcf52'] = 'Informations supplémentaires';`

I replaced "customaddresses_" by "address_" (my overriding template).

I kept :

```
{l s='Your addresses' mod='customaddresses'}
```

And to be more proper, I changed a little bit my method hookDisplayOverrideTemplate :

```
public function hookDisplayOverrideTemplate($params)
{
    $controllerName = get_class($params['controller']);
    $tpl = $this->local_path . 'override/tpl/' . strtolower(str_replace("Controller", "", $controllerName)) . '.tpl';
    if (file_exists($tpl))
    {
        return $tpl;
    }
    return false;
}
```